# Using Elasticsearch query dsl in java high level rest client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, rest-client

I have a query dsl as a string can i use the same to get/search documents from elasticsearch using java high level rest client.

Comment: Could you share that Query DSL and expected output?

Comment: @DarshanMehta 

I have some a query DSL like this :-

GET index_name/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "user_name": "user_name"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

I want to create some abstract api in java that get the data from elasticsearch using the query dsl.

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Comment: @tryingToLearn 
I haven't  find the solution with high level rest client.
For a turnaround i have used JEST CLIENT ELASTICSEARCH which gives same solution
https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest